# R dataframes to multi sheet Excel Work

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying to save quite a few data frames to a multi sheet Excel sheet and am getting some weird errors.

```
library(xlsx)
save.xlsx("WorkbookTitle.xlsx", mtcars, Titanic, iris)

save.xlsx <- function (file, ...)
  {
      require(xlsx, quietly = TRUE)
      objects <- list(...)
      fargs <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE))
      objnames <- as.character(fargs)[-c(1, 2)]
      nobjects <- length(objects)
      for (i in 1:nobjects) {
          if (i == 1)
              write.xlsx(objects[[i]], file, sheetName = objnames[i])
          else write.xlsx(objects[[i]], file, sheetName = objnames[i],
              append = TRUE)
      }
      print(paste("Workbook", file, "has", nobjects, "worksheets."))
}
```

gave me an actual workbook but when I try to do this with my dataframes, i get this error:

```
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usedError in .jcall(cell, "V", "setCellValue", value) : 
  method setCellValue with signature ([Ljava/lang/String;)V not found
```

I removed row names but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: The error sounds as if you might have more than one element in a cell of one of your dataframes.  Check with `str(df)` that they are valid dataframes and that none of the variables is of type `list`.

Comment: @AndrewGustar at least one has come up as Classes. Should I look into changing it to a dataframe?

Comment: Yes, I think `write.xlsx` needs it to be at least coercible to a standard dataframe - a grid of rows and columns with one value per cell.  'Classes' doesn't sound like a standard dataframe variable type - you probably need to tidy that up somehow (or remove it, depending on what it is).